# Remove straight line from multiple routes on Google Maps API

Tags: java, android, google-maps, google-polyline

I am adding LatLng points into the "Array-list" from "JSON web Service" and then I have a for loop to add poly-lines to the map; except that it can show the extra straight line.
The extra straight line is in between initial and final point.
  How can I remove that straight line from the Google-map? I can check this on Google but it doesn't find any solution Please help me! Thanks in advance[image]

```
for (int m = 0; m < Path.size(); m++) {
                                    lat = Path.get(m).latitude;
                                    lng = Path.get(m).longitude;
                                    latLng1 = new LatLng(lat, lng);
                                    coordLisst.add(latLng1);

                                }
                                options.addAll(coordLisst)
                                        .width(6)
                                        .color(Color.RED);
```